# Is it possible to pluck out the argument types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
const A = {
  func(a:string, b:number){}
}

type INFERRED_ARGS = {
  // necessarily I want `Argument resulted to be { a:string, b:number }` here
  [key in keyof typeof A]: Argument<typeof A[key]>
};
```

Note: `Argument` keyword is just for demonstration.

Comment: Unlikely, but you may be able to get a `readonly [string,number]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do things like this:

```js
type Args<T> = T extends (...args: infer U) => infer R
  ? { args: U, result: R }
  : never;

const func = (a: string, b: number) => {
  return '';
};

const foo: Args<typeof func>;
// foo has type:
// {
//   args: [string, number];
//   result: string;
// }
```

You cannot extract the names `a` and `b` as these are just the variable names inside that function, it is not captured by the type information.

Comment: This definitely solves what I was looking for. I should not have used interface for that. Ofcourse variable names wont be picked up. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Typescript's standard library includes the generic types `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>` which extract a tuple of argument types, and the return type of a function, respectively. It is not possible to extract the names of the function's parameters.

```js
type Foo = (x: number, y: string) => boolean

// [number, string]
type Args = Parameters<Foo>

// boolean
type Ret = ReturnType<Foo>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAKAHgLigOwK4C2ARhAE4A0UI2AzsKQJY4DmAlMgHxREIA2EAQxwAoYaEhQAgqWY1kUAAoDSAghGBkaAHnhwOY8NABK6+SeB5SOACqGdCfUA)